# asp.net bypass dynamically loaded page to get to target

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, response.redirect

background:

- existing asp.net web application employs a number of dynamically-loaded user
  controls and pages
- many of these pages and user controls depend on parent page context
- a new project containing “version 2” of the application needs to integrate with aforementioned legacy version in production while “version 2” continues to be developed

scenario:
I’m using a response.redirect with a parameterized URL to navigate from “version 2” page back to a dynamically-loaded legacy page - a "page 1", if you will.  This works fine.  However, the ultimate goal/target is to navigate directly to a dynamically-loaded legacy page which is “2 clicks away” from the initial target.  The “clicks” would be from the dynamically-rendered controls.

question:
Is it possible from my “version 2” page in the code-behind to navigate directly to this ultimate target?  When I call the user click procedures in code immediately following the call stack from the initial redirect, it still lands me on legacy page 1.

So the basic question is more conceptual in terms of handling direct navigation several “hops” into dynamically-loaded pages.  In other words, can navigation be controlled in code-behind from dynamic controls without actually rendering them back to the client onscreen?

Much obliged for any help to get me beyond this impasse.

/John

Comment: too vague and misguided - dynamic page navigation/rendering issue has been solved after deep dive into existing source code

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the issue was how to reach a dynamically generated target page from a point in the application which required multiple click events (i.e. multiple round trips), and reduce that to a single round-trip in the code-behind.

Invoking consecutive click events in the code-behind without rendering would have been a recursive violation of the page life-cycle.

Essentially, sequential click events cannot be leveraged in 1 round trip - the solution is to leverage the relevant underlying procedure calls, and/or write new ones in order to yield the target page.